# How accurate is Dijkstra Algorithm?

Tags: graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Is it necessary that Dijkstra Algorithm always finds the shortest part between two veritices?

Comment: I think you mean shortest "path" instead of "part"

Comment: Yupp. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the edge weights in your graph is positive, Dijkstra's algorithm finds the shortest path. But it doesn't work if the graph has negative weights. For finding shortest path in graphs with negative edge weights, algorithm like Bellman-Ford is used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.  It has been [proven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm):

> Proof of Dijkstra's algorithm is constructed by induction on the
>   number of visited nodes.
>
> Invariant hypothesis: For each visited node **v**, **dist[v]** is considered
>   the shortest distance from source to **v**; and for each unvisited node **u**,
>   **dist[u]** is assumed the shortest distance when traveling via visited
>   nodes only, from source to **u**. This assumption is only considered if a
>   path exists, otherwise the distance is set to infinity. (Note : we do
>   not assume **dist[u]** is the actual shortest distance for unvisited
>   nodes)
>   The base case is when there is just one visited node, namely
>   the initial node source, in which case the hypothesis is trivial.
>
> Otherwise, assume the hypothesis for **n-1** visited nodes. In which case,
>   we choose an edge **vu** where **u** has the least **dist[u]** of any unvisited
>   nodes and the edge **vu** is such that **dist[u] = dist[v] + length[v,u]**.
>   **dist[u]** is considered to be the shortest distance from source to **u**
>   because if there were a shorter path, and if **w** was the first unvisited
>   node on that path then by the original hypothesis **dist[w] > dist[u]**
>   which creates a contradiction. Similarly if there was a shorter path
>   to **u** without using unvisited nodes, and if the last but one node on
>   that path were **w**, then we would have had **dist[u] = dist[w] +
>   length[w,u]**, also a contradiction.
>
> After processing **u** it will still
>   be true that for each unvisited nodes **w**, **dist[w]** will be the shortest
>   distance from source to **w** using visited nodes only, because if there
>   were a shorter path that doesn't go by **u** we would have found it
>   previously, and if there were a shorter path using **u** we would have
>   updated it when processing **u**.